# Add a database to use with locate command?

Tags: console, locate

I would like to know if anyone knows how I can create a database of a file system on my computer. so I can choose this data base to search for files on this file system efficiently.

I ask this question since in man locate I found that I can choose a database for a different file system. Also would be great if /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db
database can have the data of 2 disks

any approach ideas or others would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure if you appropriately modified /etc/updatedb.conf that it would accomodate multiple mount points (disks).  In fact, I thought it looked at everything except the paths that were pruned off (contained in the /etc/updatedb.conf).

Thus you could still use the locate command to select the files from the generated database.

Comment: thanks, a lot for the info, I solved it mounting the disks into another directory, becuase media is pruned and I think is not a good idea to unprune media/